# Is there any send/receive button in Mail?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I really like Mail - and it's my default mail app. I want to ask, is there any send/receive button where I could manually refresh the app? Thanks!

Rai

Answer (score 1):

No such button present in Mail, but there is an option to "Always watch for new mail" in Preferences. Enabling it will display "New Email" notifications even if Mail is closed.